# How to connect steel posts to build a shelf unit?

Tags: construction, metal, conduit, steel, gardening

The posts or conduit needs to be galvanized as I'm using this for growing herbs.

Im not sure if I would have to get this welded or if theres a simpler way to put something like this together. (fittings possibly?)

Im considering 1/2" to 1" for thickness for conduit, or 1 1/2" galvanized fence posts.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Because you're not talking about a gigantic weight (presumably) have you considered UV Stable PVC or Painting PVC with some UV Stable paint?

Comment: It will need to hold a couple hundred pounds of soil when complete, plus I kind of wanted to make it somewhat 'permanent'.  Thanks though :)

Comment: I retract my previous comment. If you were going to be in the 300-400lb range distributed, I would still go for PVC that can be chemically "welded" and even designed to incorporate irrigation. I think what you're looking for would be more along the lines of the systems that hold together handrails with clamps, gussets and brackets. Good luck! Sounds like a fun project!

Comment: [Kee-klamp](http://keesafety.co.uk/products/kee-klamp) or similar. See [example](https://www.jwz.org/bookcase/) and [another](http://metastatic.org/standing-desk/)

Comment: Perfect! Thats exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you!

Comment: The question went from strategic to shopping. Voting to close.

Comment: Why close the question now., the question was answered. Go ahead close the door after the horse got out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of structural steel and piping *comes galvanized already*.  For instance most silver/gray colored iron pipe.  (not black pipe used for gas; apparently methane or its additives don't play well with zinc.)   And you can get galvanized pipe fittings to link them, in most shapes.

Piping may not be the way to go.  You may want to go with sectional steel channel, one being the Unistrut style and its many clones.  Again, available galvanized.

If you *really* wanted to go PVC or EMT conduit, despite the weight load, consider designing a truss.  Crazy large geodesic domes are made using EMT conduit as the structural members.

There are many ways to arrest corrosion other than galvanizing.  My preferred way is to knock off the rust with a wirebrush or sander, then Rustoleum 7769 Rusty Metal Primer which seems to control light surface rust reasonably well, then any of a variety of topcoats (primer alone will not hold; look any any automobile that's driving around with rust busting through the primer).

Answer (score 0):

Forget pvc. It will wobble. Go to Stratco. Get smallest tube steel. They will show you their joining brackets. You will just need an impact driver and will take an hour. All galvanised. Not flimsy.